# PayPal IPN with PHP returns HTTP 400 with IPN Tester and Sandbox

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm trying to integrate PayPal IPN into my app. I'm at the first stage of testing. I have copy/pasted this code:
https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/paypal_ipn.php

Then, using the IPN tester here:
https://developer.paypal.com/developer/ipnSimulator

I send an IPN. This returns the message "We're sorry, but there's an HTTP error. Please try again." If I check the inspector, under network there is a 400 error.

The output to the log file is as follows:

```
[2015-08-14 14:21 America/Chicago] 1. HTTP request of validation request:POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1
Host: www.sandbox.paypal.com
Accept: */*
Connection: Close
Content-Length: 20
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

 for IPN payload: cmd=_notify-validate
[2015-08-14 14:21 America/Chicago] 2. HTTP response of validation request: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 14 Aug 2015 19:21:30 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: c9MWDuvPtT9GIMyPc3jwol1VSlO=YSr2aJL5kxPX894uugNhw87ur4ChWoHJjtJLIZ9nqfiS9rOgWSW42T0tPoLj2JpHZ8vclaVwel-vg4GrLQOJbNTcQ42AuITkYbaKVfj_pmpwVXpIB73Wn2C3dLPNWkcXdYWZdmOycOF4sVLHNVsO_cd3XZD2i3hzpptLUBvIKIsJjjq3WggwFQYYZRn-i0RuQnEZtZ1JQph-nT90PrSeqr2l7XNeY0ozqr0bwaZDyAhEWp01pozPZTughjbHzwoDjTetpkBWZkscNLNSomTYRzVlzZNYmVYKF1nh7Hmfb6AM2D_bR3d5cK6DXQcraaj3ZtGNifboMPRVbvJycti1ZOW3RNqFrxZhXkCRPYty_DGfSwo4pHiWW33B0AVCAvHXM7yv2uGjUc1SQjfl3ZXpmVsnpwsEme2MS7DGiwPZEApXixhvFT-9PJCiKm4; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: cookie_check=yes; expires=Mon, 11-Aug-2025 19:21:31 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: navcmd=_notify-validate; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: navlns=0.0; expires=Sun, 13-Aug-2017 19:21:31 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: Apache=10.72.108.11.1439580090758032; path=/; expires=Sun, 06-Aug-45 19:21:30 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Connection: close
Paypal-Debug-Id: bf09526fb4efd
Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=name%3DSANDBOX3.WEB.1%26silo_version%3D880%26app%3Dappdispatcher%26TIME%3D3124743765; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
Set-Cookie: Apache=10.72.128.11.1439580090740911; path=/; expires=Sun, 06-Aug-45 19:21:30 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=14400
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

INVALID
[2015-08-14 14:21 America/Chicago] 4. Invalid IPN: cmd=_notify-validate
```

I have checked for errors on my server, and there are none. I have also tried modifying the code to account for the following comment:

```
// CONFIG: Please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set the directory path
// of the certificate as shown below. Ensure the file is readable by the webserver.
// This is mandatory for some environments.
//$cert = __DIR__ . "./cacert.pem";
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cert);
```

I am at a loss for what else I can check.

Comment: If you follow the procedures outlined in this article about [how to test PayPal IPN](https://www.angelleye.com/test-paypal-ipn/) you should be able to track down your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the form build in the linked suggestion, which led to additional proof that the php code was working fine. After following the process through a few more times and tracking the IPN simulator network requests I decided to try connecting to my site via http instead of https. Connecting via https was the trigger to causing the 400 error. Connecting over http works and does not generate the errors.